# NameError when using input()

Tags: python, input, python-2.7

So what am I doing wrong here?

```
answer = int(input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?"))
if answer == ("Beaker"):
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect! It is Beaker.")
```

However, I only get

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\your pc\Desktop\JQuery\yay.py", line 2, in <module>
    answer = int(input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      NameError: name 'Beaker' is not defined
```

Comment: you are using `int` and you are expecting a `string`? try this `int("5")` and this `int("hello")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `input` instead of `raw_input` with python 2, which evaluates the input as python code.

```
answer = raw_input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?")
if answer == "Beaker":
   print("Correct!")
```

`input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`

- [input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)
- [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Also you are trying to convert "Beaker" to an integer, which doesn't make much sense.

You can substitute the input in your head like so, with `raw_input`:

```
answer = "Beaker"
if answer == "Beaker":
   print("Correct!")
```

And with `input`:

```
answer = Beaker        # raises NameError, there's no variable named Beaker
if answer == "Beaker":
   print("Correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `int` and expecting string on input.?use `raw_input` for your case, it captures every possible values of `answer` as string. so in your case it would be something like this:

```
answer = raw_input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?")
#This works fine and converts every input to string.
if answer == 'Beaker':
   print ('Correct')
```

OR

if you are using only `input`. expect 'answer' or "answer" for string. like:

```
>>> answer = input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?")
What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?'Beaker'#or"Beaker"
>>> print answer
Beaker
>>> type(answer)
<type 'str'>
```

similarly to use `int` in `input`, Use it like:

```
>>> answer = input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?")
What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?12
>>> type(answer)
<type 'int'>
```

But if you type:

```
>>> answer = input("What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?")
What is the name of Dr. Bunsen Honeydew's assistant?"12"
>>> type(answer)
<type 'str'>
>>> a = int(answer)
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
```